# SQLite slowdown as database grows (rolling log)

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, database-performance

I'm having a problem with massive sqlite slowdowns in my c application and
have no idea whether it's to be expected or I'm not using sqlite correctly.
The db uses a rolling log like that explained here http://dt.deviantart.com/journal/Build-Your-Own-Circular-Log-with-MySQL-222550965.

The table being written to has about 170 float columns and is set to roll over at
2 million rows. The query to insert rows looks like:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (row_id, <170 column names>) values ((SELECT
COALESCE(MAX(log_id), 0) % max_rows + 1 FROM table_name AS t), <170 floats>)
```

The insert time seems to grow linearly with the number of rows. The first
insert takes much less than a second while the 60,000th takes 30 seconds. Is
this what you'd expect? The db is stored on an ext3 formatted SD card could
this be a factor?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `MAX(log_id)`, you're asking the database to find the maximum value of `log_id` in the table.  If you have no index on that column, the only way it can determine the maximum value is to scan the entire table.

You can add an index to the `log_id` column with an SQL command like;

```
create unique index idx1 on table_name (log_id);
```

Mind you, this could take a while on a particularly large table.  If you can, try it on a copy first.